# How to get Store logo and image alt in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to get store logo and logo alt tag and homepage URL of store through to store id. I am using below code but its not working for me.

```
            $storeid=1;

            $store['id']=$collections->getStore_id();   
            $store['image']=Mage::app()->getStore($storeid)->getLogoSrc();
            $store['alt']=Mage::app()->getStore($storeid)->getLogoAlt();
            $store['storeurl']=Mage::app()->getStore($storeid)->getHomeUrl();
```

In return i am getting

```
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Default Store View
            [image] => 
            [alt] => 
            [storeurl] =>
```

Let me know where i am doing wrong or how to get store logo and logo alt tag and homepage URL from store ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution for this. We can get this with below code all detail is store in table core_config_data so you use this

```
  $logo_src =   Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src', $store_id)


  $logo_alt =   Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_alt', $store_id)
```